# How do I pass in .env to an installed package in Node 20

Tags: node.js

I am developing a package in Node 20. It heavily relies on environment variables for configuration. I am thinking ahead when users install my package as so:

`npm i my-package`
or globally
`npm i -g my-package`

How would the user go about specifying an .env file to run my package with? So far, I can see there is [a basic documentation available](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v20.6.0) that says the user needs to pass in an argument to Node.
`node --env-file=config.env index.js`

But there are no instructions on how to pass the --env-file flags to an installed package.

Any directions are appreciated.

I looked at `npx` which is really `npm exec` but I'm confused when I do `npx -h` the help doesn't really specify anything to do with node arguments.

Comment: Read the environment variables from `process.env`.

Comment: That being said, most libraries do and should request that initialization parameters are passed into a function instead of being read from the environment. It's the dependent program that should decide whether the variables should come from the environment or not.

Comment: @Codebling The question is how do i get them from .env file to process.env for an installed package in Node 20?

Comment: Of course this is not a hard rule, it depends on what kind of library you are developing

Comment: https://github.com/entropitor/dotenv-cli

Comment: It has to be done at launch time, so nothing that a library can force or control

Comment: @Codebling dotenv-cli would do the trick, thanks, was hoping for a non-library solution, npx at most :)